# Is there a function to get an element by its DOM address?

Tags: python, xml

A function like this:

```
getElementDom("root.child.grandchild")
```

returning the `grandchild` element.

Comment: can you show the corresponding html code?  you might be looking for something called "jQuery selectors"

Comment: Use XPath, for example with [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's called XPath:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import xml.etree.ElementTree 
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

doc = StringIO("""
<document>
 <title>People working for me</title>
 <person xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
         xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
   <name>Jim</name>
   <title>Porch Light Switcher</title>
   <foaf:homepage rdf:resource="http://example.com/his_page" />
 </person><person>
   <name>Joe</name>
   <title>Bottle Washer, 3rd class</title>
   <nick xmlns="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">Joe-Joe</nick>
 </person>
</document>
""")

tree = ET.parse(doc)
print tree.findall("person/title")
```

Of course, [lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) is a lot better:

```
f = StringIO('<foo><bar></bar></foo>')
tree = etree.parse(f)
r = tree.xpath('/foo/bar')
```

- [XPath Support in ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm)
- [XPath support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath)
- [XML Path Language (XPath)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function in the DOM standard, no. You probably want to use the [`lxml` library](http://lxml.de/) instead and use XPath expressions:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(filename)
for element in tree.xpath('./root/child/grandchild'):
```

`lxml` builds on top of the [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) rather than the (archaic) DOM APIs. The standard library ElementTree API implementation supports limited XPath expression searching too:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse(filename):
for element in tree.find('./root/child/grandchild'):
```